# HttpResponseException do not sent to sentry in Laravel

Tags: laravel, exception, sentry

Exceptions that were throw new exception with HttpResponseException do not arrive to Sentry.
I have a controller with the following code:

```
public function search($request): mixed
{
    try {
        $response = $this->myService->search($request);
        return is_array($response) ? new MyResource(["response" => $response]) : $response;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500));

    }
}
```

If i change the catch scope to throw error like this way below, its sent successfully to Sentry. It works if `$ex` is of Exception instance too.

```
    } catch (\Throwable $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
```

My Sentry Config in config/sentry.php is with default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` class, you will find the `HttpResponseException` in the `$internalDontReport` array.

That is the reason why this exception is not sent to Sentry.

You can override the array in `App\Exceptions\Handler`, and remove the `HttpResponseException`:

```php
protected $internalDontReport = [
    AuthenticationException::class,
    AuthorizationException::class,
    BackedEnumCaseNotFoundException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    MultipleRecordsFoundException::class,
    RecordsNotFoundException::class,
    SuspiciousOperationException::class,
    TokenMismatchException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
];
```